# Getting single Subfolder name but not its contents

Tags: windows-10, powershell, environment-variables

This seem so simple but I can not seem to find the answer. I have a root folder called Processing. Inside the root folder, a user will move a folder with hundreds of other folders and files. I do not know what the name of that folder will be called.

All I'm trying to do is get that single subfolders name and put it in a variable.

Thank you in advance!

```
**Such as:**
$folderName = SUBFOLDER
PROCESSING
  -> SUBFOLDER  (All I need is this name)
        ->F1    (Not any of these)
        ->F2
        ->F3
        ->etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude the F1, F2, etc., don't use the -Recurse option. Also, use -Name to get just the name of the subfolder without any of the additional data. So,

```
$foldername = get-childitem -Path C:\Temp\Processing -Directory -Name
```

will put the name of that subfolder (you said there was only one) in the $foldername variable.

Comment: Though the OP did not state, it, I chose to use recurse make the assumption that that OP could be starting high in the tree. My temp folder has dozens of folder and subfolders in it. That NewFiles folder in not below temp, it's deeper, hence the recurse. to find the folder no matter where is was in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the -filter and -Directory switch.

```
$folder = 'NewFiles'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter $folder -Directory -Recurse

    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                
d-----        30-Dec-18     20:39                NewFiles
```

***Update for the OP.***

Correct, NewFiles is a grand child of temp.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter $folder -Directory -Recurse).FullName

# actual UNC
D:\Temp\PngFiles\NewFiles
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I try to use the above code, all I get is the name "NewFiles" it doesn't pull the name of the folder in the root folder. If I'm understanding correctly in your code the path D:\Temp is scanned pulling the subfolder name "NewFiles" correct? That is what I'm trying to acheve but it seems like "NewFiles" is just set and the Get-ChildItem isn't doing anything.

Comment: Correct, NewFiles is a grand child of temp.